Biological approch for AI consciousness?
To me it is very obvious that consciousness can only result from

Existing in a confined area that allows differentiation between self and environment
having basic desires i.e. staying alive, risk aversion
Cut motivations from a human and he will die. We exclusively do something to satisfy desires.

Are there research groups working on AI that has stuff like that programmed, coupled with the ability to recieve sensory inputs from its environment?

"To me it is very obvious that..." - Explaining why you think that might help you get useful answers. As would defining consciousness.

Consciousness is the ability to reflect about existence. Being aware to exist, requires formation of an ego. This is naturally driven by experiencing cause and effect between the confined body and the external environment. This requires sensory inputs.

Without needs there could not be an ego. The brain would not have a reason to do anything. Every activity is driven by a need.

While I can´t exclude alternative formations of consciousness it seems most promising to take nature as an example.

It's all good as long as you provide the definition you're using here. Different people mean different things when they use that word, so it's good to define it up front so you don't end up talking past each other.

These are fine ideals, but it comes down to how. Despite the enthusiasm, our methods are still crude. Success is often measured statistically, which means that even when everything is the same between runs, solutions might be different (even as much as never learning).
Reinforcement learning is most similar to what you describe. We give an agent a stimulus, and it takes action to maximize the reward. Research is grappling with how to do this on ever-larger scales in more reliable ways. Of course, inspection into what is learned is an ever-growing science, and without it, we cannot determine what notion of “self” an agent might have.
